# Como é que crio uma funcao somaCum() para arduino? C

Tags: c, c++, arduino

Foram medidos os ângulos ang = {0.0,46.0,91.2,134.7,179.2}, a unidade é deg (degraus). 
Tenho que implementar código que inicializa os valores como array global, e depois, define a função void somaCum(float arr[]){} que calcula as somas cumulativas(Scum={S1,S2,S3,...,Sn}={X1,X1+X2,X1+X2+X3,...,X1+X2+...+Xn}
) de cada elemento, e escreve os valores para a consola . Apresente um exemplo de utilização (invocar função mais resultado na consola).

```
float acc[]={0.0,46.0,91.2,134.7,179.2}
int accSize = 5;

void setup(){
 Serial.begin(9600);
 somaCum(acc);
}
void loop(){}
void somaCum(float acc[]){
 for(int n=0;n<accSize;n++){
  //Como é que faço a função?
}
```

Comment: Você quer imprimir o resultado de todas as somas, ou somente a soma final?
Se for o resultado de todas as somas, você quer apenas visualizar as somas ou também deseja armazena-las em um array?

Comment: Resultado de todas as somas. So visualizar as somas. O enunciado da questão é esse mesmo.

Answer (score 1):

Só isso aqui resolve seu problema amiga?

```
void somaCum(float acc[]){
for(int n=0;n<accSize;n++){
float soma = acc[n] + acc[n-1];
Serial.print(soma);
  }
}
```

Comment: O resto do codigo esta bem?

Comment: n teria que mudar mais nada?

Comment: Em teoria sim, posso verificar mais tarde no meu arduino, mas eu acho que isso faz oq vc quer, tenta executar e manda o erro q retornar